# Typescript: Typed Array connect input to output in a function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a function that does this

- Takes a string corresponding to a number type,
- returns a typed array
- Upon execution the user receives information about the exact typed array returned

But after trying for a long while, I haven't been able to connect the input and output.

```js
const typedArrays = {
  int8: Int8Array,
  uint8: Uint8Array,
  int16: Int16Array,
  uint16: Uint16Array,
};

type TypedArrays = typeof typedArrays

function doSomething<T extends keyof TypedArrays>(input:T): TypedArrays[T]{
    return new typedArrays[input]([1,2,3])
}
```

**Edit:** incorporated a few of the suggestions in answers (still do not solve the main problem.)

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgEwIICdMEN4RgF4YBvAKBhgEswoAOALhgEla6td4AaCmAVxr0mAVUHtseHpUEBGAGxNWUeR0m8BteSNlzV3XoIDMAJkW0TeqfyOmYo88cvrBcgCxMAQlQDm9qG6dpWjdPHyUAiX1KADMAGxAcKBMmADF4xItIqziE-3cYNNyIzh4AXwBuMjIEFBgAFSQ0PQJiGuQQaLhGjEiIKui+MGAoKnAYVBAAZRAAW2QoAAsabwAeOphkAA8oZDBUAgBrZHgO+u7mgD4AChpEPigGOoBKJgaUHs4IAG06gF1ySiUTDzPiYMAwMDIADuXXezS+t3uvyuXxkXGMXEMvyeZFKQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TypedArrays` type would work if it was just a simple `typeof typedArrays`

```
type TypedArrays = typeof typedArrays;
```

Since you want to return instances of the typed arrays and your object contains constructors you need to use [InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) for the return type of your function

```
function doSomething<T extends keyof typeof typedArrays>(input: T): InstanceType<TypedArrays[T]> {
    return new typedArrays[input]() as InstanceType<TypedArrays[T]>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgEwIICdMEN4RgF4YBvAKBhgEswoAOALhgEla6td4AaCmAVxr0mAVUHtseHpUEBGAGxNWUeR0m8BteSNlzV3XoIDMAJkW0TeqfyOmYo88cvrBcgCxMAQlQDm9qG6dpWjdPHyUAiX1KADMAGxAcKBMmADF4xItIqziE-3cYNNyIzh4AXxgcAlBIKABuMgQUGAAVJDQ9AmJG5BBouDaMSIh6smi+MGAoKnAYVBAAZRAAW2QoAAsabwAeZphkAA8oZDBUAgBrZHhe-pRr7sHOCAA+AAoaRD4oJmaASjNoHATZCtFA7AYdADazQAuk9SLxKJhVnxMGAYGBkAB3G7tIYQ96faEvH4VAisAFAkHIMEoB54CBQ2H1UpkMjVaAwaIgEBEWYLZarDZgbwvADkYlFPzIAHppZRKAA9AD8bPAEBAsWQADp4iKuSAfiN2bAAEY4TC8jHY+6Q0U5DLGUVEw0yuXy5WqyAa7W6l5mzCGoA)

Comment: That still wont work, I just forgot the keyword `new` in the example.

Comment: @Minsky updated the answer with a solution that returns instances

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that `TypedArrays` is an interface declared as

```
{
  T: typeof typedArrays[T];
}
```

So `input` is typed as `"T"`, but `"T"` is not assignable to `keyof typeof typedArray`

It is correct from the response above to type better `TypedArrays`, but you could even not use it:

```
const typedArrays = {
  int8: Int8Array,
  uint8: Uint8Array,
  int16: Int16Array,
  uint16: Uint16Array,
  int32: Int32Array,
  uint32: Uint32Array,
  uint64: BigUint64Array,
  int64: BigInt64Array,
  float32: Float32Array,
  float64: Float64Array,
};


function doSomething<T extends keyof typeof typedArrays>(
  input: T
): typeof typedArrays[T] {
  return typedArrays[input];
}

const a = doSomething("int8"); // Int8ArrayConstructor
const b = doSomething("float32"); // Float32ArrayConstructor
```

Also, please keep an eye about the use of `new`.

Take for example `int8: Int8Array` in `typedArrays`, remember that `Int8Array` is not a type, but a `var`:

`var Int8Array: Int8ArrayConstructor`

So this will result in an error:

```
function doSomething<T extends keyof TypedArray>(input: T): TypedArray[T] {
  return new typedArrays[input]; // Error
}
```

This is because we are returning a truly `Int8Array` from a function that should return `Int8ArrayConstructor`.

In order to avoid this, do the following:

```
const typedArrays = {
  int8: Int8Array,
  uint8: Uint8Array,
  int16: Int16Array,
  uint16: Uint16Array,
  int32: Int32Array,
  uint32: Uint32Array,
  uint64: BigUint64Array,
  int64: BigInt64Array,
  float32: Float32Array,
  float64: Float64Array,
};

type TypedArray = typeof typedArrays;

function doSomething<T extends keyof TypedArray>(input: T): TypedArray[T] {
  return typedArrays[input];
}

const a = new (doSomething("int8"))(); // Int8Array
const b = doSomething("float32"); // Float32ArrayConstructor
```

Comment: Thanks but we need to return `new typedArrays[input]` and that breaks.

Comment: @Minsky I just updated the example, tell me if this help you

Comment: It does but I am trying to get a clean execution as this is an API. This won't be useful.

Comment: @Minsky maybe a better solution is make a switch inside the body of the function, this would resolve in a more verbose function but should works